# Creating SNMPD Agent - Writeable objects and more

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

Apologize for the long post, majority of it are config files that need to be shown.

I've been creating my own SNMP agent.  For creating my MIB and snmpd.conf file I've just searched the web for answers.  For actually implementing the handlers I've used the example.c/.h found at http://www.net-snmp.org/dev/agent/example_8c_source.html

I'm using another PC (all Linux) to test my implementation and so far I've only been able to get *snmpwalk/snmpget* commands to work.

I've setup the WriteMethod function inside my source file for my setable objects.  Problem is, I do not think this code is getting executed when trying to set the object.

Below is an example of trying to set the object:

```
root@jt:/usr/share/snmp/mibs# snmpset -v 2c -c communityNameHere -m MIB-NAME-HERE.txt 10.20.30.40 1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1 s "0"
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Cannot find module (MIB-NAME-HERE.txt): At line 0 in (none)
Error in packet.
Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)
Failed object: iso.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1
```

I've also tried to use snmpset without the -m option.  I've tried using -m +MIB-NAME-HERE.txt as well.

**Question** - I have snmp.conf commented out.  How can it not find the module when the MIB I specify is in /usr/share/snmp/mibs ?

Below is my MIB :

```
MIB-NAME-HERE DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, Integer32, enterprises,
    NOTIFICATION-TYPE                       FROM SNMPv2-SMI
    OBJECT-GROUP, NOTIFICATION-GROUP        FROM SNMPv2-CONF
;

testSnmp MODULE-IDENTITY
    LAST-UPDATED "201505200000Z"
    ORGANIZATION "www.example.com"
    CONTACT-INFO
         "email: support@example.com"
    DESCRIPTION
        "MIB Example."
    REVISION     "201505200000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
        "version 1.0"
    ::= { enterprises 12345 }

--
-- top level structure
--
   testSnmpValues       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { testSnmp 1 }

testSnmpValuesGroup OBJECT-GROUP
    OBJECTS { testObject
            }

    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
           "Group of all test variables."

    ::= { testSnmp 4 }

--
-- Values
--

testObject OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(1..4096))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Test Example"
    ::= { testSnmpValues 1 }
```

**Question** - What is the purpose of :

```
   testSnmpValues       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { testSnmp 1 }

testSnmpValuesGroup OBJECT-GROUP
    OBJECTS { testObject
            }

    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
           "Group of all test variables."

    ::= { testSnmp 4 }
```

Now for my snmpd.conf file :

```
###############################################################################
#
# snmpd.conf:
#   Test snmpd configuration file.  (See EXAMPLE.conf as a reference)
#
###############################################################################
# By default snmp looks here:
# /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf.
# Use '-C -c <configfile>' to override.
#

###############################################################################
# Access Control
###############################################################################

#       sec.name  source          community
com2sec testall    default         communityNameHere
#---- Community 'communityNameHere' uses security name 'testall'. 'source' selects which IPs can connect.


####
# Second, map the security names into group names:
#               sec.model  sec.name
group TestGroup  v1         testall
group TestGroup  v2c        testall
group TestGroup  usm        testall

####
# Third, create a view for us to let the groups have rights to:
#           incl/excl subtree                          mask
#view all    included  .1                               80
view testview included .1.3.6.1.4.1.12345
#---- testview - A view which only allows access to Test OIDs.

####
# Finally, grant the groups access to the 1 view with different
# write permissions:
#                context sec.model sec.level match  read    write   notif
#---- Grant read access to TEST group for all security models.
access  TestGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  testview testview testview

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# load the testsnmp module
dlmod testsnmp /usr/local/testsnmp.so
```

**Question** - Is there something I am missing to make an object writeable?  I've seen other snmpd.conf files with different formats but I assume that shouldn't matter?

Comment: I've tried adding `rwcommunity communityNameHere` to the snmpd.conf file and still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't need a MIB for net-snmp to work. It is enough when you have the OID specified in the .c file.

Are you trying the snmpset/get/walk on a remote PC or on the same one. 
I had to specifie in my snmpd.conf   the 
-> agentAddress  udp:161
Without it i didn't had access.

Comment: It was actually the syntax of the snmpset command that was the problem.  I needed to add a .0 to the end of the element I was attempting to set.  Reason for it, I think it has something to do with the non-supported type of the object but without going through the underlying code, I wouldn't trust what I've read.

Answer (score 1):

Your MIB file missing "END" at the end, you can validate it here: [simpleweb mib validation](http://www.simpleweb.org/ietf/mibs/validate/)
I named my community "public" and had to add this in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

`com2sec ConfigUser     default       public
 com2sec AllUser        default       public
 group   ConfigGroup     v1           ConfigUser
 group   AllGroup        v2c          AllUser`

Now you shall be able to do your tests with v1.
I had to do `export MIBS="MY-MIB"`, whereas MY-MIB.txt is my MIB file, which I put info /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs/. I don't remember exactly whether it was required for mib2c tool or if you can skip defining MIBS variable.

Then you could start snmpd with -d switch to see debug output, start your agent and can do testing. I had to enable ports used by snmpd in my firewall, which were blocked by default. I can test read/write on my dummy value with:

```
snmpget -v1 -c public localhost:10161 MY-MIB::test2.0
MY-MIB::test2.0 = INTEGER: 43 tests
snmpset -v1 -c public localhost:10161 MY-MIB::test2.0 = 123
MY-MIB::test2.0 = INTEGER: 123 tests
```

As long as you have a working agent, this shall work, you can use also mib2c to create simple sub-agent for your test-MIB and test it with it, just to make sure your config+agent is all right.

Comment: I should have noted - I didn't display the entire MIB which is ultimately my fault.  Come to find out, I needed to add a .0 after the OID I specified to set. +1 for your explanation.